# collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute VB .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Sub Procedure which accepts a filtered users collection as parameter and i would like to get the value of userID from that collection, I can see it successfully add's the first userID but in the Next it raises an exception.

```
  Private Sub GetUserID(ByRef filteredusers As Business.HR.UserCollection)
  If filteredusers IsNot Nothing Then
   For Each uIDs As Business.HR.User In filteredusers
      filteredusers.Add(uIDs.UserId)
    Next 
    'exception here as System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  End If
  End Sub
```

Kindly help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood the question, because the explanation is in the error message, basically; you are trying to modify the collection you are in the midst of enumerating

Comment: I am just trying to retrieve the user ID from the filterusers collection (which has Many properties like username , user ID , positionid)

Comment: while iteration you cannot add to collection being iterated...thats the reason for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this exception is that you're modifying the collection you're iterating over.

You have a couple options:

```
1.  Create a separate variable to store the values in. 

  Private Sub GetUserID(ByRef filteredusers As Business.HR.UserCollection)
          dim myFilter as new Business.HR.UserCollection
          If filteredusers IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each uIDs As Business.HR.User In filteredusers
                    myFilter.Add(uIDs.UserId)
                  Next 

          End If
          filteredusers = myFilter
  End Sub
```

2. Assign a separate variable to iterate over.

   ```
     Private Sub GetUserID(ByRef filteredusers As Business.HR.UserCollection)
             dim myFilter as Business.HR.UserCollection = filteredusers
             If filteredusers IsNot Nothing Then
                   For Each uIDs As Business.HR.User In myFilter
                       filteredusers.Add(uIDs.UserId)
                     Next              
             End If                 
     End Sub
   ```